# exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1 in Ecipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

When importing a Maven project into Eclipse I get the following error:

> No marketplace entries exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1 error

And it looks like it results in further build problems post import - like

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (execution: default, phase: generate-sources)

Am I missing a plugin or is there anything wrong with my pom.xml?

Installed m2e:

> > m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components)  1.5.0.20131218-1208 org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
> >
> > Eclipse Java Development Tools    3.8.2.v20130116-090414-8-8nFu3FNOfwKLRuqgXKIy9z0I83 org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group   Eclipse.org
> >
> > Eclipse Platform  4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7    org.eclipse.platform.feature.group  Eclipse.org
> >
> > Eclipse RCP   4.2.2.v20130129-152330-7IARAABrMQkGSvMgQnUlz-DQz00h org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group   Eclipse.org

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the m2e plugin of Eclipse doesn't know of exec-maven-plugin you could solve that by the following:

```
   <build>
      <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.2.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>java</goal>
                                            <goal>exec</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
   </build>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answe. Just adding this to pom.xml results in Unrecognised tag: 'pluginManagement' error.. Is tere a specific section in the file where this should be added? Sorry, just learning Maven.

Comment: You need to add that into `<build>...</build>` area. Answer updated accordingly.